# Mimic persistent python request session with curl in shell

Tags: shell, curl

Anyone with python knowledge
can someone explain difference between raw curl request vs python request session.get or session.post

i have a url when i place url in browser file downloads also when i use python session to get url it download
but when I use curl with same headers it fails says error 302 or 410

how can we mimic python request persistent session with curl

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get(url)
```

> download file
> but with curl url
> it fails with error 410 or 302

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Download the file by following too many redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738620/download-the-file-by-following-too-many-redirections/738621#738621)

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -k -L -b ~/.cache/mycurl.cookiejar \
-c ~/.cache/mycurl.cookiejar -s <URL> -C -
```